# Rename multiple *.html.erb files

Tags: ruby

I have Folder > Sub folders with stored *html.erb Files, which I need to rename to *.haml Extension.

```
\folder
  \folder
    \*html.erb
    \*html.erb
    \*html.erb
    \*html.erb
  \folder
    \ ###
    \ ###
    \ ###
  \folder
```

I want to exclusively use Ruby script for this task.
So far I have following Ruby script:

```
f_p = "/home/ocean/Documents/testr/"
Dir.glob(f_p + "*").sort.each do |f|
  filename = File.basename(f, File.extname(f))
  puts filename
end
```

But it only prints the first part of extension, and then I need somehow to correctly rename it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby,

```
dir_root = "./folder"
Dir.glob( File.join(dir_root, "/**/*") ).sort.each do |file|
  if file.match(/\.html\.erb$/)
    File.rename(file, file.gsub(/html\.erb/, "haml"))
  end
end
```

Not in Ruby, but in Bash with rename command:

```
rename 's/\.html\.erb$/\.haml/' folder/*/*.html.erb
```

Comment: I've corrected my code thanks to the @warantesbr's answer. Instead testing on the basename, I've used `match` on the whole filename.

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by toch is almost correct, but it has a couple of issues:

1. The major issue is that the condition to rename is testing if "erb" (the method extname returns just the last segment) includes "html.erb", which will never be true;
2. The minor issue is that the regular expression used on the rename it's not escaping the dot and not testing for the end of the line as well;

So i decide to make those ajusts:

```
base_dir = "./views"
Dir.glob( File.join(base_dir, "/**/*") ).sort.each do |file|
  File.rename(file, file.gsub(/html\.erb$/, "haml")) if File.basename(file) =~ /html\.erb$/
end
```